# Flow execution key is empty in spring webflow for multipart request - Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, spring-webflow

Our application has been running smoothly on Tomcat 6 , Jdk 7 and Spring 3.0. recently we upgraded to tomcat 7 and have started seeing strange behaviour.
There is page which has upload button which is used to upload certain excel files.
The way it works is that I click on browse button , select file and click on Upload.
After our upgrade to tomcat 7, when i click on Upload, the page is throwing exception.
Reason  : flowexecution key is empty. (it is empty not null)
Debugging through spring code, at this line

```
org.springframework.webflow.context.servlet.DefaultFlowUrlHandler#getFlowExecutionKey("execution")
```

I get empty string.

Although I can see the url as

```
http://myapplication/admin/flows/fileUploadList-flow?execution=e5s7
```

This is my jsp page

```
<form:form commandName="model" name="model" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
action="${actionPath}">
<input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>
----
---
</form>
```

The other pages are working fine.

Any idea what is going on here ? Is this problem because of multipart request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>
```

to

```
    <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>
```

Parameter name "flowExecutionKey" is changed to "execution" from SWF 2.0